# Not receiving crashes on crashlytics while do internal testing

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated crashlytics with the pod. I used to test application with Testflight. I have noticed that there were few crashed on iTunes connect but Did not received any email from fabric/crashlytics.

I Try app crash manually like exit(1) and I received an email on very next launch of the application. So assuming that crashlytics framework integrated successfully.

Do you have any suggestion where I suppose to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Our email notifications will **not** be sent on each crash as for many developers that would be overwhelming. Crashes are grouped into issues to make it easier to track which issues should be fixed within your app and here's when the emails would be triggered for an issue.

An email is sent under the following options, in relation to crashes (which are grouped into issues).

- [New Issue](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/notification.html#change-notifications) (When a brand new issue occurs - a crash that has never been seen before for your app)
- New Non Fatal Issue (When a brand new logged NSError occurs - an NS Error that has never been seen before for your app)
- Regressed Issue (When a crash is detected outside the known versions of the issue and the issue is closed. For example, you feel you've resolved the crash/issue in version 1.2 of your app and ship 1.3. If the crash re-occurs, the issue would be opened and a regression email would be triggered).
- Crash Stability Digest - This is a summary email sent when issues are detected to be trending over time or particularly high volume.

Comment: I  did not received any single email, where as itunes says that there were 8 crashes.

Comment: I tired exit app on button tap and in next 2 min I received and email with crash information details.

Comment: Sounds like you're all set, but let me know if you're still having an issue.

Comment: Yes all set, may be email notification issue... as I have details of crash at fabric. Thank you (happy)

Comment: @MikeBonnell : on a different context, is there any way to unset user identity for crashlytics instance? (use case: when user logs out)

Comment: @CerlinBoss setting the user identifier to an empty string should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with Fabric's email service as I was facing the same issue as well. But when I logged-in to my Fabric's account and check report over there, it was showing the crashes there. So please check your Fabric's dashboard. You might get your crashes listed over there.