# Not getting Email Notifications again for the same crash in crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated Crashlytics in Android application. And when I try to throw exception using this:

```
 Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
 throw(new RuntimeException());
```

An Email notification appears.

But for this same crash, If I tried again. Only crash count increases in Crashlytics for that crash. But no Email notification appears.

Note: I am receiving email notification for the crash which appears first time. But not getting notification again for the same crash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not receiving crashes on crashlytics while do internal testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857291/not-receiving-crashes-on-crashlytics-while-do-internal-testing)

Comment: It means According to you, I will not receive email for the same crash again. I will receive email only if the crash type is any of these type:
New Issue,
New Non Fatal Issue,
Regressed Issue,
Crash Stability Digest

Comment: That is correct with the clarification that an issue could become regressed in which case it would be an email about the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the frequency of emails you receive by updating your preferences in fabric account. Go to : https://fabric.io/settings/notifications to change your email preferences.